# faster way of getting difference between each element of 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays from which I am trying to find the difference for each element pair and store the difference in a matrix.

Here is the code used by me:

```
for i in range(arr1):
    for j in range(arr2):
        data[i,j] = float(arr1[i])-float(arr2[j])
```

what can be done to optimize the speed of this loop?

Comment: you can use `np.subtract.outer(arr1, arr2)` or broadcasting or `np.subtract(*np.ix_(arr1, arr2))`; broadcasting: `arr1[:, None] - arr2[None, :]`

Comment: similar: `arr1 - arr2.reshape((-1,1))`

Comment: arr1_arr2_transformation = numpy.dstack(-arr1, arr2) then do numpy.sum(arr1_arr2_transformation)

Comment: Why are you not posting your answers as answers?

Comment: @FancyDolphin are you sure? First of all `numpy.dstack` takes only one argument returns an array. Summin of it yields a scalar. I dont see how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @greole if you do a foo = numpy.dstack((a,-b)) then do numpy.sum(foo, axis = 2) you'll get the awnser. Make a= numpy.array([1,2,3]) and b = numpy.array ([4,5,6]). I think that's what the OP is asking for no?

Comment: No, besides that the solution in your comment now is different then your first comment, it doesn't work.   You can verify it easily by looking at the shape which should be `(n,n)`. In your case i get a shape of `(1, n 2)`

Comment: @timegb I don't understand what you were implying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments there are several ways to reach your goal.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [6]: a = np.random.rand(1000)
In [7]: b = np.random.rand(1000)

In [9]: %timeit a - b.reshape((-1,1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.46 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.subtract.outer(a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop
```

It seems that the reshape and the `subtract.outer` are comparable in speed. However it looks like you need to transpose the result in order to have identical results for both methods

```
In [18]: a - b.reshape((-1,1)) == np.subtract.outer(a, b).T

array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ..., 
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

**Edit** The second method proposed by @PaulPanzer seems to be the slowest.

```
In [27]: %timeit np.subtract(*np.ix_(a, b)); a[:, None] - b[None, :]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.99 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.subtract.outer(arr1, arr2) helped me solved the problem.
```

Thanks everyone